# Simulate mouse down and move left

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

in order to simulate a play effect with a jquery panorama,

I'd like to simulate that the **mouse** is **down** on it **and** that is being **moved** to a left/right side

is that posible?

same way we can

```
$('#item').click();
```

can we do something similar to achieve it?

Comment: If you are using jquery panaroma (or which ever plugin you use), it's better to figure out the event that is called when the 'mouse is down on it and that is being moved' and trigger that event directly.

Comment: @rkw how can i find out the event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent
- [MouseEvent constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for .mousedown() and .mouseup methods. They should behave the same way as .click()

Check this link http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Answer (score -1):

Its something like

```
$('selector').mousedown(function{
      $("selector").mousemove(function(event) {
        var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
        msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
        $("#log").append("<div>" + msg + "</div>");
         });
    });
```

Comment: but this is to dectect the mouse move, i want to simulate it

Comment: would you explain this "i want to simulate it"? sorry perhaps i couldn't understand what you want to do

Comment: the code I  posted, it simulates that user clicked on #item, right? well i want the same, but with the mousemove+click